# Removal of compileComponentsAsync in angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-compiler

With the release of Angular2 RC6 they remove the compileComponentsAsync

and replaced it with compileModuleSync(basically only referencing the module) now does that mean I have to create a module for every component I wish to render at runtime? or can i reference the module and only render the component i want?

below is the statement

"core: previously deprecated @Component.directives and @Component.pipes support was removed.

All the components and pipes now must be declared via an NgModule. NgModule is the basic compilation block passed into the Angular compiler via Compiler#compileModuleSync or #compileModuleAsync."Because of this change, the Compiler#compileComponentAsync and #compileComponentSync were removed as well - any code doing compilation should compile module instead using the APIs mentioned above.

Lastly, since modules are the basic compilation unit, the ngUpgrade module was modified to always require an NgModule to be passed into the UpgradeAdapter's constructor - previously this was optional."

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39297219/angular2-rc6-dynamically-load-component-from-module