# How to Get the List of services and directives available to the current component

Tags: angular

For a component `MyDemoComponent`

```
@Component({
   selector : 'my-demo-component',
   template : '<div> Demo </div>'
})
class MyDemoComponent { };
```

Which has been included in `MyDemoModule`

```
@NgModule({
  imports : [SomeOtherModule],
  declarations: [AnotherComponent, SomeOtherComponent],
  export : [MyDemoComponent]
})
class MyDemoModule { }
```

Now is there any way I can get a list of all the components , services and pipes that `MyDemoModule` makes available to `MyDemoComponent`.

From [what I have looked](http://blog.lacolaco.net/post/dynamic-component-creation-in-angular-2-rc-5/) up so far I can use `ViewContainerRef.parentInjector` which is a (sort) of collection of services I was looking for. However I am still at a loss as to how to get the list of directives and pipes that are used in `MyDemoComponent` .

I am basically trying to create a component that can dynamically create other components, similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468). However In the views of the dynamically created components I want to use the components,services and pipes registered in the parent module.

EDIT : Here I am posting the relevant section of code where the list I mentioned will help me :

```
export class DynamicComponentCreator {
  @Input() html: string;

  constructor(private vcRef: ViewContainerRef, private compiler: Compiler) {}

  ngOnChanges() {
    const html = this.html;
    if (!html) return;

    @Component({
      selector: 'dynamic-comp',
      template: html
    })
    class DynamicHtmlComponent  { };

    @NgModule({
      imports: [CommonModule],
      declarations: [DynamicHtmlComponent]
    })
    class DynamicHtmlModule {}

    this.compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(DynamicHtmlModule)
      .then(factory => {
        const compFactory = factory.componentFactories
               .find(x => x.componentType === DynamicHtmlComponent);
        const cmpRef = this.vcRef.createComponent(compFactory, 0);
    });
  }
}
```

As you can see the module I'm creating inside cannot be configured to use the services/components/pipes available to parent module. This code is slightly modified from what is seen in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39410355/how-to-use-variable-to-define-templateurl-in-angular2#answer-39411464)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obtaining `Injector` reference is simple:

```
constructor(private injector:Injector)
{
}
```

You dont need to get component list yourself, everything is resolved automatically if your module is properly configured.

See `ComponentFactoryResolver`, `ComponentFactory` documentation.

---

By default you can not access module instance from component, but you could provide module yourself:

```
    {
        provide    : 'module', //better use OpaqueToken
        useExisting: forwardRef(() => AppModule),
    }
```

Now can inject module into component: `@Inject('module') module:any`
Then use Reflect metadata package to extract module parameters.

Comment: Actually I am trying to create a component dynamically as seen in this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39410355/how-to-use-variable-to-define-templateurl-in-angular2#answer-39411464.  Here the dynamic component is placed in a dynamically created module which is unable to get the components/services/filters from above... will injector take care of them too ?

Comment: Updated the question to better explain what I'm talking about.