# Dynamic templateURL with Angular 2 version of the Angular UI Bootstrap library

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I am creating a dynamic template URL using the following code  [How to use variable to define templateUrl in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39410355/how-to-use-variable-to-define-templateurl-in-angular2#answer-39411464), but I need to use a datepicker in the template and I had problems to add the Angular UI Bootstrap library (Angular 2 version). The error is

*"No provider for NgbDateParserFormatter"*

I added NgbModule and FormsModule to the section imports

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule, NgbModule.forRoot(), FormsModule ],
    declarations: [DynamicHtmlComponent]
})

class DynamicHtmlModule {}
```

I created a plunker version https://plnkr.co/edit/kWoSTi?p=preview
If the field date in the file `src/articles/first.html` is uncommented the application doesn´t work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would leverage the following way to do it working :

```
this.compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(DynamicHtmlModule)
  .then(factory => {
     const moduleRef = factory.ngModuleFactory.create(this.vcRef.parentInjector);

     const compFactory = factory.componentFactories
        .find(x => x.componentType === DynamicHtmlComponent);

     const cmpRef = this.vcRef.createComponent(compFactory, 0, moduleRef.injector);
});
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/MnYtBi?p=preview)**

> One note: you can use `NgbDatepickerModule` instead of `NgbModule`. It
>   will improve performance **[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/7n4oz2?p=preview)**

Answer (score 0):

You can import NgbDatepickerModule this way:

```
@NgModule({
imports: [
    ...
    NgbDatepickerModule.forRoot()
],
```

This should fix the "No provider for NgbDateParserFormatter"