# How to render angular variables using innerHTML - Angular2

Tags: html, angular, interpolation

In my application their is some text which is coming from a constant file which is declared like this:

```
  export const EmpStrings = {
    data:  "Welcome {{employee.name}}"
  }
```

And In my component file there is an object called `employee`.

```
   public employee = { name: 'xyz', dept: 'EE' }
```

Now In my HTML I want to use it like this:

```
<div class='e-data' [innerHTML] = "EmpStrings.data"></div>
```

But this didn't seems to be working.
I tried various variations:

```
[inner-html] = "EmpStrings.data"
[innerHTML] = {{EmpStrings.data}}
[innerHTML] = "{{EmpStrings.data}}"
```

But none of them seems to be working.

Comment: @Vega yes I already tried all the possible ways listed there.

Comment: You need to use `JitCompiler` if you want to have binding within string. For example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39410355/how-to-use-variable-to-define-templateurl-in-angular2 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40060498/angular-2-1-0-create-child-component-on-the-fly-dynamically/40080290#40080290

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to use JitCompiler then you can parse string yourself

**component.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.html = EmpStrings.data.replace(/{{([^}}]+)?}}/g, ($1, $2) => 
      $2.split('.').reduce((p, c) => p ? p[c] : '', this));
}
```

**template**

```
<div [innerHTML]="html"></div>
```

[**Plunker Example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/x7PTr6hmUYZk1BWv9XIR?p=preview)

Comment: Is there a way to do this more generically through one of Angular's existing constructs, like a directive or pipe?

Answer (score 2):

use `${employee.name}` to bind angular variable to innerHTML

```
"data": `Welcome ${employee.name}`
```

Comment: If I use `${employee.name}` then I am getting error message that emloyee is not defined in constant file

Comment: post the employee object

Comment: use `this.employee.name`

Comment: why are you trying to add angular variable to constant

Comment: I need parse some long strings and then add some content via vairables. And in constant file I have declared this like: 

message: "Hello mr. employee.name"

And then any controller which wants to use can use it via message.

Comment: How about cutting "Hello mr. employee.name"  in two parts and doing {{string1}}{{string2}} with string1="Hello" and string2="employee.name". It's not a universal solution but a shorcut

Answer (score 0):

Angular doesn't interpolate strings like this, as far as I know one of the reason is security. The const doesn't have the context where your employee is in hence you see the error saying employee is not defined.

You could do this:

Change your constant:

```
export const EmpStrings = {data:  "Welcome "};
```

then:

```
<div class='e-data'>{{EmpStrings.data}}{{employee.name}}</div>
```

But if for some reason you must use `[innerHTML]`:

1. In your component class, add a method:

   `getWelcomeMessage(){return EmpStrings.data + this.employee.name;}`
2. in the component view:

   `<div class='e-data' [innerHTML] = "getWelcomeMessage()"></div>`