# Angular 2 Lazy loading a NgModule in a NPM module with angular router

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-cli

I have been lazy loading modules in routes e.g.

```
export const HomeRoute: Route = {
  path: '',
  component: HomeComponent,
  canActivate: [AuthGuard],
  children: [
    {path: 'dashboard', loadChildren: 'app/+dashboard/db.module#DashboardModule'}
  ]
};
```

I would like to put my "pages" into NPM modules.  What is the route to the node_module that I should use in the loadChildren attribute?  I am using angular-cli 1.0.0-beta.16

I have tried

```
{path: 'lazy', loadChildren: '../node_modules/hello-world/components#HelloWorld' }
```

also

```
{path: 'lazy', loadChildren: 'hello-world/components#HelloWorld' }
```

The exported class is: -

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'hello-world',
    styles: [`
       h1 {
            color: blue;
        }
    `],
    template: `<div>
                  <h1 (click)="onClick()">{{message}}</h1>
               </div>`
})
export class HelloWorld {

    message = "Click Me ...";

    onClick() {
        this.message = "Hello World!";
        console.log(this.message);

    }
}
```

Is there anything else I should try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This currently isn't possible - see a response from the AngularJS CLI team here: -

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2601

> "This is a very relevant question. I don't think we support it in the
>   CLI atm." (Currently version beta 17)

Datumgeek has implemented lazy loading from modules in a different way (outside of CLI) here: - https://github.com/datumgeek/a2dyn/blob/master/README.md#development-server

I will update the answer if it becomes possible in the Angular CLI in the future

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to do this without CLI? I.e. Basing on angular webpack starter from angularclass? I tried to link to my modules via '../node_modules/path_to_my_module' and the only thing which is not working is AOT compilation.

Comment: A workaround can be found here (one of comment at about the end of the issue): https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6373, but this one is not lazy load, neither AOT compilation support.

Answer (score 0):

check that HelloWorld is an exported class and not a 'default export'. otherwise it won't work.

Comment: Apologies for the delay, I was off on holiday.  Yep, the HelloWorld class is just exported, I've edited the question to show the class in full

Comment: It might be an issue with angular-cli not exposing webpack configuration as it's mentioned here that he had to use webpack directly rather than CLI https://github.com/datumgeek/a2dyn/blob/master/README.md#development-server