# Context Menu - view loader Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to make a contextual menu.
but inside the menu i need to load any view that i want.
I want to load any component/view and possibly pass some information to it.

is this posible?
Thx!

Comment: Checkout [how to pass data from component to component](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html)

Comment: Yep that is not the main issue, the main problem is that i need a service that loads components and show that component inside the contextmenu.component

Comment: `<app-sub-component *ngIf="service.shouldLoadSubComponent() | async"></app-sub-component>` ?

Comment: that way you always add the same component inside, i want to load components dynamicly depending of the context you are in the app, (thus the name contextual/context-menu)

Answer (score 0):

I can't write a comment so I have to post it as an answer.
This might help you:

[Angular2 RC6 - Dynamically load component from module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39297219/angular2-rc6-dynamically-load-component-from-module)

[Angular 2.2 Dynamically load components using System.import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40652963/angular-2-2-dynamically-load-components-using-system-import)