# angular 2 load second component

Tags: angular

how can I lazy load component in angular 2? If I use the code below I get an error if I don't use both components on a html page.

Thank you,
Matej

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent, SecondComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent, SecondComponent]
})
```

Comment: I think you should just use only root Component in `bootstrap`

Comment: It's been discussed thousand times here. Please search for `lazy load` (and you can't lazy load a component. Only a module.

Comment: @Maxime Thank you, I should use modules to separate different independent components?

Comment: Yes. You should group your functionalities by modules and then you'll be able to lazy load some modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First : You can't bootstrap more than one components , it doesn't make sense.
You'd only bootstrap one root component.

Second : If you wan't to load a component lazily/dynamically , you'd need to decide in which place that component should be created/loaded dynamically and then take it from there.

Third : A dynamic component should be in declaration of the module and in the entryComponents.

There are heaps of tutorials out there related to how to load a component dynamically , one would be

[Angular2 RC6 - Dynamically load component from module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39297219/angular2-rc6-dynamically-load-component-from-module)