# Is there a way to dynamically evaluate/use an angular (angular 2+) pipe?

Tags: angular

Let's say I have a pipeVar, it can be any pipe, eg.: number, uppercase, customPipe, etc

Is there a simple way to just call something like

```
{{ myVal | pipeVar }}
```

or some special syntax like

```
{{ myVal | #pipeVar }}
```

?

The closest thing I have found so far is [Dynamic pipe in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36564976/dynamic-pipe-in-angular-2)

Comment: Check this https://plnkr.co/edit/Vz88zzWwzPbqgIpMinPp?p=preview

Comment: @yurzui Thanks for the plunker.  I was thinking about the similar implementation.  But pipes with additional arguments need to be supported as well.  Also, I think I need to support multiple pipes to be ideal, like `passThrough:[actualPipes]`

Comment: please check this plunkr https://plnkr.co/edit/xX1klYoaGMq1O2TJzu8w?p=preview

Comment: @bipinpatel But it won't work with aot. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39252944/invoke-pipe-during-run-time-using-pipe-name-metadata

Comment: @bipinpatel Your example of using <template> and dynamic pipes are exactly what I am trying to solve.  I was thinking of looking into the angular source code to see how pipes are done.  The fact that your code leverages the angular compiler teaches me some inner working of angular already.  However, if it doesn't work with aot, then it might not be an optimal solution.  But I do see how I can expand `{{ data | ' + pipe  + '}}` into `{{ data | ' + pipe  + '|' + pipe2 + '|' + ... pipeN}}` to achieve multiple pipe support

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/2lpPMUIKt59pnTNd3jCP?p=preview

Comment: can you explain pipe,pipe2 ... pipeN how it come from any service or any global defined variable?

Comment: @bipinpatel I am not sure this is what you are asking. But they will just be an array of strings.  They will be passed into a component, and that component will dynamically apply them as pipes for formatting the display.

Answer (score 0):

i have update plunkr [plunkr link](https://plnkr.co/edit/2lpPMUIKt59pnTNd3jCP?p=preview)

Change in dynamic-pipe.ts like this

```
const dynamicPipe = "";
//i have give one simple logic for example if your dynamic pipe is like
this.dynamicPipe = ['number','uppercase','customPipe']; //pipe,pipe1 ... pipeN
//now create a one variable like 'number' | 'uppercase' | 'customPipe' 
for (let i=0;i<this.dynamicPipe.length;i++){
     dynamicPipe = dynamicPipe + " | "+this.dynamicPipe[i];
}
@Component({
    selector: 'dynamic-comp',
    template: '{{ data ' + dynamicPipe + '}}'
})
```

Comment: I see.  Thanks for pointing out we can just let the compiler take care the multi pipe support.  I haven't tested the solution out for AOT, do you know if it will work with AOT?

Comment: What is AOT? i don't have idea about AOT.

Comment: Ahead of time compilation.  yurzui mentioned that it won't work with AOT.  I haven't given it a try yet though...